# is there a way to compile a c/c++ program from python?

Tags: c++, python, c, compilation

Currently I'm coding a python script to compile a C/C++ Linux kernel in the following way:

```
subprocess.check_call(["make", "-j5"])
subprocess.check_call(["make", "-j5", "modules_install"])
subprocess.check_call(["make", "-j5", "install"])
```

With these approach the commands are executed in the shell. So I was wondering if there is another way to compile the kernel using python build in libraries?

Comment: Are you asking if there's a built-in python-based compiler for C/C++? If so, the answer is no.

Comment: You could call the C compiler directly, but then you'll have to reproduce all the logic in the Makefile. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: No, these are executing directly, not through a shell. You are not redirecting stout or stderr, so you see the command output when you run the program.

Comment: would you think the approach that I have it's the best one? (to compile a c/c++ program)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ultimately, python isn't a C/C++ compiler, so you need to ship out the compiling to an external program (e.g. `gcc`).  So, there is no way to do this *entirely* in python.

Note that here python doesn't spawn any shells (although `make` might).  You could try to reproduce what `make` does entirely in python, ([there is a version of make written in python](http://benjamin.smedbergs.us/pymake/) FWIW), but honestly, it's not worth it.  You need to spawn subprocesses anyway -- you might as well use the tools which are already in place and "tried and true".

Comment: would you think the approach that I have it's the best one? (to compile a c/c++ program)

Comment: @juanp_1982 -- Since you already have the makefile, I would probably use it.  It's also sort of the standard for building things on *NIX systems.  Of course, if you need to support building things on Windows too, then `make` might not be your program.